# How to check / cancel a azure storage container delete operation

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

I know Azure Storage works with soft deletes using GC. So I want to check if a container has the delete flag and cancel this delete operation.

However, I can't figure out a way to check if the container has the delete flag.

I did check the delete container operation in the DOCs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#delete-container-container--lease-none----kwargs-

There is a lease paramater and the description says:

> If specified, delete_container only succeeds if the container's lease is active and matches this ID. Required if the container has an active lease.

Thus, I though if I acquire a new lease, I would be able to cancel the delete operation. But I can't aquire a new lease or break the existing one. I am always receiving the following error message:

```
ResourceNotFoundError: The specified container does not exist.
```

However, when I try to create the container, it gives me the following error:

```
ResourceExistsError: The specified container is being deleted. Try operation later.
```

How can I check if there is a delete flag in a container?

How can I change the lease of a container flagged with it?

Comment: Hello Pegas, I want to check if you still have more issues about this question?

Comment: Hello Ivan! I was waiting someone else answer to see if there is any different point of view, but as I have decided to move on, I will be setting your post as an answer, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot cancel the deletion of blob container, and there is no such flag.

You can request this feature in [azure blob storage user feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage).

And one more thing, the only way to cancel deletion of blob container(I think it should be recovery in your case), you should contact Microsoft in time by following this [guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-container-recovery), but no guarantee.